# Does javamelody work with spring webflux?

Tags: spring-webflux, java-melody

can anyone point me to a resource, how I can get spring-webflux and javamelody to work together?
Seems, that a servletcontext is neccessary for startup, which I don't have/need.

I'm aware of the coll metrics stuff, that comes with spring-boot 2.x, but I don't have anything to display the metrics with, and am locked to a company environment, where just installing something isn't a valid option.

Thanks,
Henning

Comment: https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/issues/760

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[javamelody](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki) is mainly based on monitoring of memory, cpu, http requests, sql requests and spring components among other things. See [javamelody-spring-boot-starter](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/SpringBootStarter) for example.

But as far as I know, Spring webflux does not use the servlet api. So what do you want to monitor?

If you just want to have graphs in a browser, then start a http server for javamelody reports like in [standalone](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/UserGuideAdvanced#embedding-javamelody-in-a-standalone-app). And if you also want to monitor sql requests and spring components, then add in your application all methods from [this example](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/blob/without-spring-boot-starter/javamelody-for-spring-boot/src/main/java/hello/JavaMelodyConfiguration.java), except monitoringSessionListener and monitoringFilter.

A new spring-boot-starter for javamelody in webflux could be created if it makes sense.

Comment: I want to monitor incoming http requests, and outgoing http WebClient requests.  Or maybe even just any metric that is exported by /acutator/metrics API, if that makes sense.

Comment: In javamelody, the monitoring of http requests is currently based on the servlet api (see javamelody MonitoringFilter.java) and on RestTemplate. This may not be what you want, so you may create a pull request for what you want and use standalone mode instead of javamelody-spring-boot-starter.

Comment: @evernat Seems, that 'servlet api less' approach is a new path of evolution spring web module. It means that webflux will be increasingly popular year after year. According to this, do you have some plans for implement a new monitoring logic base on spring webflux?